# Laravel Form Validation on POST request

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-form

I have a form which is divided into 2 parts.
The first part of the form is displayed with "GET" request when the user clicks a button. when the user fills this form and clicks next, the page is redirected to the next part of the form with a "POST" request which first saves the form and then displays the next part. 
The problem is when i try to validate the 2nd part of the form, laravel gives and error saying method not allowed.

my first controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'unit_code' => 'max:25',
        'unit_title' => 'max:255',
        'project_title' => 'max:255',
        'project_ref_number' => 'max:255',
        'storage_location' => 'required|max:255',
        'keeper_name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $notification = Notification::create([
        'unit_code'         =>$request->unit_code,
        'unit_title'        =>$request->unit_title,
        'project_title'     =>$request->project_title,
        'project_ref_number'=>$request->project_ref_number,
        'storage_location'  =>$request->storage_location,
        'keeper_name'       =>$request->keeper_name,
        'user_id'           =>Auth::user()->id
        ]);

    return view('Notification.notification_for_lmo')->with('notification', $notification);
    //return redirect()->route('show.material_List')->with('notification'); 

}
```

routes:

```
/*route to personal information form for notification*/
    Route::get('/personal_information_notification_form', 'HomeController@getNotificationForm');

    /*submit personal information and go to next part of the form*/
    Route::post('personal_information_notification_form/submit/', 'NotificationController@create')->name('submit.personal_info_for_notification');

    /*route to material list form for notification application*/
    Route::get('personal_information_notification_form/material_list/', 'NotificationController@showMaterialListForm')->name('show.material_List');

    /*submit the material list*/
    Route::post('/personal_information_notification_form/add_lmo/', 'NotificationTypeAController@create')->name('submit.add_lmo');
```

2nd controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    /*this loop is because im adding rows dynamically to the table*/
    $count = count($request->input('item_name'));

    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'material_type' => 'required|max:25',
            'item_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'risk_level' => 'required|max:255',
            'quantity' => 'required|max:255',
            'volume' => 'required|max:255',
            'notification_id' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('Notification.notification_for_lmo')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

        $data  = NotificationTypeA::create([
            'material_type'  =>$request->material_type[$i],
            'item_name'      =>$request->item_name[$i],
            'risk_level'     =>$request->risk_level[$i],
            'quantity'       =>$request->quantity[$i],
            'volume'         =>$request->volume[$i],
            'notification_id'=>$request->notification_id
        ]);
    }



        $admin = Admin::find(1);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $notification = Notification::find($request->notification_id);
        $admin->notify(new NewNotificationApplicationSubmitted($user->name, $notification->id));

        return redirect()->route('show.go_to_notification')->with('message', 'We have notified '.$user->name.' that he/she is added to SSBC')->with('status', 'info');

    }
```

In the second controller, there is a for loop because the user fills the data in a table form. (the blade file is big so i am not posting it here.)

What is the problem with this and why is this happening?

first blade:

```
<div class="well">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('submit.personal_info_for_notification')}}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                SECTION 1 - Personal Details
                            </legend>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('unit_code', 'Unit Code (if teaching):', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('unit_code', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('unit_title', 'Unit Title (if teaching):', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('unit_title', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('project_title', 'Project Title (if FYP/research):', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('project_title', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('project_ref_number', 'Ref. No (if FYP/research):', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('project_ref_number', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('storage_location', 'Storage Location:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('storage_location', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            {!! Form::label('keeper_name', 'Name of the Keeper:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} <br>
                                            {!! Form::text('keeper_name', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

2nd blade:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('submit.add_lmo') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <legend>
                                            SECTION 2 – Details of the Biohazardous Materials
                                        </legend>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                            <h4>List of Living Modified Organism (LMO)</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <input type="checkbox"/>Applicable
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <div id="LMOtablediv">
                                                <input type="button" id="addmoreLMObutton" value="Add" onclick="insRow(event)" />
                                                <table id="addLMOtable" border="1">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>No.</td>
                                                            <td>Notification ID</td>
                                                            <td>Material Type</td>
                                                            <td>Name</td>
                                                            <td>Risk Level</td>
                                                            <td>Quantity</td>
                                                            <td>Volume</td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>1</td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="notification_id" id="notification_id" value="{{$notification->id}}"></td>
                                                            <td>{!! Form::text('material_type[]', null, array('id'=>'material_type'))!!}</td>
                                                            <td>{!! Form::text('item_name[]', null, array('id'=>'item_name'))!!}</td>
                                                            <td>{!! Form::text('risk_level[]', null, array('id'=>'risk_level'))!!}</td>
                                                            <td>{!! Form::number('quantity[]', null, array('id'=>'quantity'))!!}</td>
                                                            <td>{!! Form::number('volume[]', null, array('id'=>'volume'))!!}</td>

                                                            <td><input type="button" id="delLMObutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Share your view code.

Comment: added the view as you asked.

Comment: I've looked at the form, there's no issue with the action and method. Can you try running 'php artisan route:clear' and 'php artisan view:clear' and then give it a try. Also try to copy paste the error message with more info.

Comment: still showing the same error

**QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'material_type' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `notification_type_as` (`material_type`, `item_name`, `risk_level`, `quantity`, `volume`, `notification_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , 24, 2017-05-24 01:23:19, 2017-05-24 01:23:19))**

Comment: somehow it is not redirecting back to the same page and instead going directly for the post where the laravel error is showing up.

Comment: Firstly your issue was with `method not allowed` error on form post. Now you have multiple issues. I just had a look at your controller code and it's a mess. You really need to clean up the code and the validation inside the loop is wrong. Validate using laravel's array validation. Secondly the above sql error is because your validation is wrong and yet it passes to the sql insert where it fails.

Comment: Check this to learn how to validate arrays https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays and don't do it with a loop like that.

Comment: I know my routes are a mess. i am learning laravel so things are all over the place. Sorry for that. 
regarding validating array, i have tried that as well and it still gives the same error. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144967/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-mill3r).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an issue in the validation rules, you wrote it in wrong way.
2. The exception thrown because a null value trying to saved in the database for the `material_type` column that is not a nullable field.

---

To fix the validation issue, remove the loop of the validation rules and try this instead:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'material_type'     => 'array',
    'material_type.*'   => 'required|max:25',
    'item_name'         => 'array',
    'item_name.*'       => 'required|max:255',
    'risk_level'        => 'array',
    'risk_level.*'      => 'required|max:255',
    'quantity'          => 'array',
    'quantity.*'        => 'required|max:255',
    'volume'            => 'array',
    'volume.*'          => 'required|max:255',
    'notification_id'   => 'array',
    'notification_id.*' => 'required|max:255',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return view('Notification.notification_for_lmo')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

---

If you are sure that all inputs has values and there is no empty values, make sure that the properties are exists in the `$fillable` array in the Eloquent model.

Comment: tried as you have said, but i get an **ErrorException in View.php line 402: Undefined offset: 0** ERROR

Comment: Yes this happen maybe because the array values are dynamic generated, so you should deal with it in your view

you can flush some inputs from returning back to the view, and you can test this by removing the call of `withInput` function